# Objective-C object exists in memory after being released

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I'm learning objective-c memory management stuff (with no ARC) and I came across some common problem. It was mentioned here a couple of times, so I'm not asking you "what on earth!?", but rather "Do I understand correctly?"

Problem:

Documentation says:

```
- (NSString *)fullName {

    NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@",

                                          self.firstName, self.lastName] autorelease];

    return string;

}
```

> You own the string returned by alloc. To abide by the memory
>   management rules, you must relinquish ownership of the string before
>   you lose the reference to it. **If you use release, however, the string
>   will be deallocated before it is returned (and the method would return
>   an invalid object)**. Using autorelease, you signify that you want to
>   relinquish ownership, but you allow the caller of the method to use
>   the returned string before it is deallocated.

So let's try:

```
// Method defined in one on my class:
-(NSString*) returnString {
    NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"returned String"]; 
    NSLog(@"1) Address in method = %p", [str self]);
    [str release];
    NSLog(@"2) Address in method = %p", [str self]);
    return str; 
 }

// In main: 
        NSString* str = [myObject returnString];
        NSLog(@"String is: [%@]", str);
        NSLog(@"3) Address in main = %p", [str self]);
```

-

```
 Output:
    1) Address in method = 0x100002a50
    2) Address in method = 0x100002a50
    String is: [returned String] // <--
    3) Address in main = 0x100002a50
```

So, if I understand well, the problem is, the it is hard to predict when exactly memory will be freed? Or actually, the specific place in memory has been only marked as "freed" and that's all... Am I right?

Comment: it is freed, just lucky enough not get allocated again yet

Comment: Edited. guitar_freak, swearing doesn't belong on Stackoverflow. For more info, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79974/whats-the-so-policy-for-swearing.

Comment: @occulus I didn't notice that. Thanks for this edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSString` is very smart about avoiding allocation/deallocation in many situations. That makes it a very bad pick for testing deallocation and learning about memory management semantics in Objective C.

In this case you are allocating an object from a literal (which never gets deallocated). Because the newly initialized object is a copy of an immutable object, the initializer would just return the literal (which, again, never gets deallocated).

You should, for example, use `NSObject` or a custom derived class to test deallocation.

Another great help would be to enable zombies, as this makes sure you immediately notice the first access on a deallocated object.

> So, if I understand well, the problem is, the it is hard to predict
>   when exactly memory will be freed?

Well, object lifetime is perfectly deterministic (when not using the deprecated Mac OS X garbage collector). The only problem is with autorelease pools: You usually don't know if an object is autoreleased, so you cannot make any guesses if it lives **longer** than you might expect.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence ;) But why Apple do not use some NSOBject example :D

Comment: @guitar_freak Because proper memory management still applies to `NSString` as well as any other object. `NSString` just sometimes does not crash where expected. Sidenote: The string in the Apple example probably behaves like normal objects, as it is not constructed from a literal.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str1 =@"parag";
NSString*str2=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"parag"];
NSLog(@"%p %p", str1, str2); //str1 and str2 both are same  
  //  0x100002098 0x100002098
```

This is related to internal optimization. you must release str2.

**NOTE:** This relies on undocumented and not-guaranteed behavior of the compiler and the initWithString: method. Both might change at any point.

Comment: It's important to add that this relies on undocumented and not-guaranteed behavior of the compiler and the `initWithString:` method. Both might change at any point.